# Transforming an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

The function $f(x)$ is defined in the interval $(-\infty, a]$, where $a$ is some real number.

If I have an improper integral of the form

$$\int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) dx \tag{1}$$

and I need to decide if it converges or diverges, can I always transform it to this one

$$\int_{a}^{\infty} f(2a-x) dx \tag{2}$$

and study the integral (2) instead of (1)?

I am saying that (1) is convergent if and only if (2) is convergent.

First of all, is this statement true?

Also, in fact... I am also claiming that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{\infty} f(2a-x) dx$$

I think it is true (just by geometric considerations) because the graphs of the two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x) = f(2a-x)$ are symmetric with respect to the line $x=a$.

How can we justify this statement more formally?

**Why I am asking this?** Because in my book all criteria for convergence/divergence (of improper integrals) are given only for integrals of the kind (2). So that made me thinking that... OK, I need to have some way to deal with integrals of the kind (1). And as a result I came up with this transformation.

Comment: It seems that the you have performed u-sub and brought the bounds from $[a,\infty)$. So the both integrals you are speaking of are one and the same. So if first integral diverges or converges then so does the second one respectively.

Comment: OK... I have no idea what u-sub is. I came up with this simple transformation on my own while reading the book. My book doesn't really cover any subs in improper integrals. In proper ones - yes, it covers.

Comment: U-substitution works for all integrals which have bounds. So when $x=2a-u$ is put in the first integral it gives the second integral.

Comment: @RAHUL Not quite. If we put (mechanically) $x=2a-x$ in (1) we also have to do it in the $dx$ (right?), and then the sign changes. That was another thing that confused me that... OK, we make a substitution in $f(x)$ but not in the $dx$. So it's kind of strange. But I think the statement (as formulated here) is true. It would be good if an expert clarifies all this. I am a bit confused here (which is why I am asking).

Comment: Note the criteria is the same for convergence, either $\lim\limits_{M\to+\infty}\int_a^Mg(x)dx$ exists or $\lim\limits_{M\to-\infty}\int_M^af(x)dx$. So there is no real need to convert one to another.

Comment: @zwim I am not sure what you mean. I will wait for detailed answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In section 179: *Application to infinite integrals of the rules for substitution and integration by parts* in *[A course in pure mathematics](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/38769/38769-pdf.pdf)* by G. H. Hardy the substitution of improper integrals is explicitly stated. It is based upon the substitution rule together with integration by parts for definite integrals. We find

> **Transformation by substitution:** Suppose that
> \begin{align*}
> \int_a^{\infty}\phi(x)\,dx\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> is convergent. Further suppose that, for any value of $\xi$ greater than $a$, we have, as in $\S$161,
> \begin{align*}
> \int_a^{\xi}\phi(x)\,dx=\int_b^{\tau}\phi\{f(t)\}f^{\prime}(t)\,dt,\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> where $a=f(b),\xi=f(\tau)$. Finally suppose that the functional relation $x=f(t)$ is such that $x\to \infty$ as $t\to \infty$. Then, maing $\tau$ and so $\xi$ tend to $\infty$ in (2), we see that the integral
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{b}^{\infty}\phi\{f(t)\}f^{\prime}(t)\,dt\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> is convergent and equal to the integral (1).
>
> On the other hand it may happen that $\xi\to\infty$ as $\tau \to -\infty$ or as $\tau \to c$. In the first case we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\int_{a}^{\infty}\phi(x)\,dx}&=\lim_{\tau\to-\infty}\int_b^{\tau}\phi\{f(t)\}f^{\prime}(t)\,dt\\
> &=-\lim_{\tau\to -\infty}\int_{\tau}^b\phi\{f(t)\}f^{\prime}(t)\,dt\color{blue}{=-\int_{-\infty}^b\phi\{f(t)\}f^{\prime}(t)\,dt}.
> \\
> \cdots\qquad\qquad&
> \end{align*}

which is the relevant part to answer your question. We can use the same arguments as above to derive
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^a\phi(x)\,dx=-\int_{b}^\infty\phi\{f(t)\}f^{\prime}(t)\,dt
\end{align*}
and with $f(t)=2a-t, f^{\prime}(t)=-1$ and $b=f(a)$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\int_{-\infty}^a\phi(x)\,dx=\int_{a}^\infty\phi(2a-t)\,dt}
\end{align*}

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It is not formulated so clearly in my book. I don't think subs in improper integrals are covered at all. Thank you. I guess $x=f(t)$ has to be a bijection, right? At least for sufficiently large x?

Comment: @peter.petrov: You're welcome! A substitution is not necessarily a bijection, but we  often prefer at least an injective mapping.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x)dx$$
Put $x=2a-u \implies dx=-du$.
$$-\int_{\infty}^{a}f(2a-u)du$$
According to properties of definite integrals,
$$\int_{a}^{\infty}f(2a-u)du$$
Which is second integral you are talking about.
Secondly, you shouldn't use same variable for different bounds for 2 or more integrals.
In the description you claimed that,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{\infty} f(2a-x)dx$$
So it's not correct to use the same variable for both integrals with different bounds. Instead, do this.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{\infty} f(2a-u)du$$
Doing one U-substitution(As i have done in the starting), says that it's true.

Comment: Check the second integral you wrote, I think you mean from minus infinity to $a$ there. Also, what rule or theorem allows me to put $x=2a-u$ to start with? If I can do that, then of course I have no problem and I don't need the geometric considerations and so on.

Comment: Noo it's $\infty$ , because $\lim_{x\to-\infty}2a-x$ clearly goes towards $\infty$ not $-\infty$

Comment: Technically it IS correct to use the same variable since it is a dummy one, but I agree it helps comprehension to change for another one. I think your formulation is a bit too strong.

Comment: If plus infinity is correct is in the second integral, then I am again confused. What formal grounds do we have to make this substitution and manipulate the upper and lower bounds of the integral like that? Is this just based on the very definition (of improper integral) ? If not, what is it based on?

Comment: Never mind, I think I was able to work it out based on your notes. Thanks.